# Return all results from a Query on a single row

Tags: sql

I have a query that will return all the results for matching row values between two tables.

The tables are `Students` and `StudentRace`. The match in the `WHERE` statement is `STUDENTS.ID = STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID`.

I am trying to return the column `STUDENTRACE.RACECD` where all the matching RACECDs are in a single row in the resulting table.  The query does something different, however.  IF a STUDENTID has more than 1 RACECD it does not repeat each RACECD in a single row for the STUDENTID.  It will return a separate row for each RACECD that matches the STUDENTID.Here is my query:

```
select 
    STUDENTS.ID as ID,
    STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_NUMBER,
    STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID as STUDENTID,
    STUDENTS.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME,
    STUDENTS.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME,
    STUDENTRACE.RACECD as RACECD,
    STUDENTS.ENROLL_STATUS as ENROLL_STATUS
from 
    STUDENTRACE STUDENTRACE,
    STUDENTS STUDENTS
where 
    STUDENTS.ID = STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID
    and ENROLL_STATUS = 0
```

Here is the result for a STUDENT ID = 23:

```
StudentID Racecd
23        B
23        W
```

This is close but not exactly what I would like to see.  I would like the result to be:

```
StudentID Racecd
23        B,W
```

or something similar to that.  I think I may need the `CONCAT` function and possibly a nested `SELECT` statement as well, but I am not sure.  I am new to SQL so I am not sure how to move forward.

Comment: What `RDBMS` are you using? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You SELECT 7 columns. but your result only has 2 columns?!?

Comment: And every single one of your aliases is unnecessary, no need to use an alias if you aren't actually giving it a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Like jarlh said I am not sure how you select 7 columns but result in 2?
but Listagg is what I think you are looking for. You can separate it by any delimiter (in this case I put comma). Also any outlying columns will need to appear in the group by

```
 select 
        STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID as STUDENTID,
        listagg(STUDENTRACE.RACECD,',') as RACECD
        from STUDENTRACE STUDENTRACE,
        STUDENTS STUDENTS
        where STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID
        AND ENROLL_STATUS = 0
    group by STUDENTRACE.STUDENTID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want there two records to become one, you want to **group by** something, **aggregating** on something else. In this case you want a single record for each student so you can group by the `student_id`, and you want all races aggregated so you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` (in MYSQL, but you can use corresponding aggregation function if in other RDBMS) to concatenate the races. It would be like this:

```sql
SELECT s.id, s.name, GROUP_CONCAT(sr.race)
FROM students s join studentrace sr on s.id = sr.student_id
GROUP BY s.id
```

That is the base to get what you want, then you can add the other fields you are interested in on the select and on the where filters.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad59d6/1/0

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand it now.  This returned exactly what I was looking for from the query.  If I can rate this response somewhere it would be a 10 out of 10.

Comment: Glad this helped you. Please accept it as correct answer for the question if its the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you might want to try the following code.

```sql
create table Person (
  Name nvarchar(450)
)

insert into Person values ('Fabio'), ('Laura')

select stuff((select ',' + Name from Person for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

The above **select** statement returns the following string.

```
Fabio,Laura
```

Comment: Well, I was looking for the query actually as my db is under the hood in a student information system, but this does help me in another project.  Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that my answer was helpful to you, @rwood – please, feel free to upvote it  :)